How can i add functionality to squares in a grid in JavaScript?
I've made a grid using HTML,CSS & JavaScript based mainly on the code on the answer to this question on Stack Overflow Creating a 16x16 grid using JavaScript. My problem is that I want to make classes for each individual and I'm not sure that I have done it right. So for example I want to be able to click on an individual square and it console.log what square it is.
I've tried adding the code below to JavaScript but I'm unsure if it works.
    cell.classList.add('cell');
    cell.id = 'cell-${c}'

Code Snippet
(attribution: Nidhin Joseph)


const container = document.getElementById("container");

function makeRows(rows, cols) {
  container.style.setProperty('--grid-rows', rows);
  container.style.setProperty('--grid-cols', cols);
  for (c = 0; c < (rows * cols); c++) {
    let cell = document.createElement("div");
    cell.innerText = (c + 1);
    container.appendChild(cell).className = "grid-item";
  };
};

makeRows(16, 16);
:root {
  --grid-cols: 1;
  --grid-rows: 1;
}

#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1em;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(var(--grid-rows), 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--grid-cols), 1fr);
}

.grid-item {
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  text-align: center;
}
<div id="container">
</div>




The JavaScript code shown is CSS...  Could you perhaps update this to a [mcve] as a runnable code snippet?

If you want to add an id you can do it as you did but by using template string (not quote) like this     cell.id = cell-${c}  in the loop or also by using the setAttribute method. To add the class you can add as you did cell.classList.add('cell') after appending the cell in the loop

Here we're using one event handler for all the squares by listening on the parent. I also added CSS rule for .grid-item:hover. You can always store values as data-something attributes of the elements.
container.addEventListener("click", function(ev) {
  var div = ev.target
  alert(div.innerText)
})



const container = document.getElementById("container");

function makeRows(rows, cols) {
  container.style.setProperty('--grid-rows', rows);
  container.style.setProperty('--grid-cols', cols);
  for (c = 0; c < (rows * cols); c++) {
    let cell = document.createElement("div");
    cell.innerText = (c + 1);
    cell.setAttribute("data-something", "my c is " + c);
    container.appendChild(cell).className = "grid-item";
  };
};

makeRows(16, 16);

container.addEventListener("click", function(ev) {
  var div = ev.target
  alert(div.getAttribute("data-something"))
})
:root {
  --grid-cols: 1;
  --grid-rows: 1;
}

#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1em;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(var(--grid-rows), 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--grid-cols), 1fr);
}

.grid-item {
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  text-align: center;
}

.grid-item:hover {
  background: gray;
  cursor: pointer;
}
<div id="container">
</div>




Can i ask, why have you used a var variable rather than a let or const variable? I have no interest in supporting old browsers so is there another reason.

no reason, just a matter of self preference
